# Parallel port output

Tags: parallel

I have a small board that controls some appliances through the parallel port.

What i want to do is to put on high/low pin X with out modifying the rest of the pins (short story, control each pin individuality)

Example: 
D0-D5 = 1
what i want D0 = 0 and  D1-D5 = 1

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which OS? Which language. C++ Boost library has a very open license, is cross-patform and very reliable. It has a asio module, which I am currently using to cotnrol a serial port (http://www.webalice.it/fede.tft/serial_port/serial_port.html). Maybe this could work out for the parallel port too. Good luck!

Comment: Also google search for "parallel port terminal" (without the quotes) turns up loads of results. Haven't researched them, however.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in this situation I keep a variable with the whole byte, change the bits I want and then write it back to the port.

Example in C:

```
PortValue = 0x00;    // Set all bits to 0
LPT = PortValue;

PortValue |= 0x01;   // Set the bit 0 to 1
LPT = PortValue;

PortValue &= ~0x01;  // Set the bit 0 to 0
LPT = PortValue;
```